# How to add tables to database with foreign key?

Tags: module, database, customer, extend

I'm trying to extend costumers to add some wholesale info we need, so I'm trying to create a module with an InstallSchema to create, let's say, the table 'wholesale_info' with some columns and getting the user ID from 'customer_entity'.

What I've done so far is

```
<?php

namespace Custom\AddUser\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface {

    public function install( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $table1 = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('Wholesale_Customer')
        )->addColumn(
            'customer_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Customer Id'
        )->addColumn(
            'num_colb',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Collaborators'
        )->addColumn(
            'website',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Website'
        )->addColumn(
            'facebook',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Facebook'
        )->addColumn(
            'instagram',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Instagram'
        );
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table1);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

This does nothing, if I try to run set:up this just gives an error.
I've seen some tutorials but the more I see the more I get confuse with this.

Any help? :D

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Rui Silva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I add Foreign key between my custom table `article_product_rel` and core product table `catalog_product_entity`. `product_id` is field in my table whereas `entity_id` is field in core product table. So, a foreign key is established between both fields.

```
<?php
 
....
 
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0) {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            if (!$installer->tableExists('article_product_rel')) {
                $table = $installer->getConnection()
                    ->newTable($installer->getTable('article_product_rel'))
                    ->addColumn('main_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['nullable' => false,'identity' => true,'primary' => true, 'unsigned' => true])
                    ->addColumn('article_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true])
                    ->addColumn('product_id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, 10, ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true], 'Magento Product Id')
                    ->addForeignKey(
                        $installer->getFkName(
                            'article_product_rel', //newtable
                            'product_id', //newtable field
                            'catalog_product_entity', //reference product table
                            'entity_id'//reference table id
                        ),
                        'product_id', //newtable field
                        $installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity'),
                        'entity_id', //reference table
                        Table::ACTION_CASCADE
                    )
                    ->setComment('Article Product Attachment relation table');
    
                $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
            }
    
            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So you just use UpgradeSchema and create the table if it does not exist? No need for InstallSchema?

Comment: InstallSchema just runs one time. UpgradeSchema runs everytime you run `setup:upgrade` command but don't forget to change version. this line `if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0)` update this value to a greater one everytime i.e `1.0.5` and also change it in module.xml.

Comment: If you want to run `installSchema` go to your database and search for setup_module table. Delete you module from there and then installSchema would run when you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! Now I need to figure out how to add data there :p

Comment: You can add data in installData or UpgradeData. Or directly inserting into database(for testing) or through model. Depends on your requirement.

Comment: I'll have to do it by model I guess the data comes from a form, that's another topic, if I need some help I'll surely create other question! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.3 it is best practice and easier to use db_schema to create database tables and their keys etc.:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html